# Topmost winform hides select menus on web pages

Tags: c#, winforms, z-order, eo.webbrowser

I'm using *[EO.WebBrowser](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/WebBrowser/Default.aspx)* in a project and it works very well. The component is used in a winform project for a very stripped down web browser. One of the requests from the client is that the application is to be topmost, above all other windows, always, until closed. This works fine by using `setWindowPos`.

```

```
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
```

```

This works fine with the exception of select menus on web pages. The menus that are supposed to turn up are hidden behind the application form. For some reason the z-order of the menus aren't correct. Opening a new window form works flawlessly, but then the new form knows its parent. That's perhaps not the case when it comes to select menus.

[image]

Is it possible to get the select menus to show upp properly on web pages and keep the topmost settings of the winform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, this is not possible in current version.**